# Creating Excel database to lookup value based on ID to generate certificate in form of jpg or pdf to be printed

Tags: excel, database, excel-formula

I want to make database in excel which is when i lookup value based on unique ID will show the result in form of certificate (jpg,pdf) to print.
I have more than 500 certificate file (jpg/pdf) where should i stored them so when i lookup the data based on unique ID in excel it will link to 500 certificate file and lookup the spesific ID based on the Unique ID in Excel.
after that if the ID Matches with the certificate file, it generate to print the certificate.
how do I do that?

would be appreciate if someone could give some insight.
warm regards

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You will get a better answer to your question if you provide more details.  However, it looks like you wish to `create a form in Visual Basic` which will `display an image with a textbox` when a cell is clicked and `populate the textbox with the cell value`.  To get you started, here is a link to tutorials for creating user forms in Excel VBA: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/vba_userforms.htm  From there it will be quite straightforward to add a picture and a textbox to the form, and then populate the textbox on the FormLoad event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is straightforward to use a combination of `CONCATENATE` to join the elements together (including your UID) to build the filepath and `HYPERLINK` to launch the file on click.

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Root Folder | Name_UID | FileType | HYPERLINK (Formula) |
| 2 | C:\certificates\ | 123456 | .png | =HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE($A$2, B2, C2), B2) |
| 3 |  | 234567 | .png | =HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE($A$2, B3, C3), B3) |

Clicking cell D2 or D3 will open the file in whatever default application is specified on the system.

NOTE: This assumes all of your files are located in C:\certificates\ however this can be modified to be anywhere you like.